# how to turn on Server power supply Lite-ON model PS-2122-8L1 without server chassis

Tags: power-supply-unit

I wanted build 48v DC power from 4 12v power supply units. Eventually i got my hands on Lite-On PS-2122-8L1 server psu. But after getting it, i am still unable power it on with out chassis. i mean i dont have a server, But i want to power it for my battery projects and also to smart chargers to deliver high power.

i tried shorting,adding resistor to pin 33 and one more pin which is soldered, like for HP psus but i think this has 8 small pins both top and bottom.
[image: Top Pins]
[image: Bottom Pins]

So anybody can help me power this thing up. Or can provide output connector pinouts, Circuit diagram etc., anything related which helps me in powering this PSU.

I have attached some pictures of the power supply. Let me know aything related to it.
[image]
[image]
[[image][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhLWw.jpg)
[image]
[image]

Thank you all..

Comment: Try asking this over at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: HI, Anybody searching answer over this, i have found it here. https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=34258309&postcount=13 and here https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=34258309&postcount=16 . Also i have commented to make sure the answer is found. https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=45839239&postcount=4551 Thankyou for down-voting, because not everyone is perfect like you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pinout for PSU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKi50.jpg)
Anybody searching answer over this, i have found it here. [rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=34258309&postcount=13](http://%20rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=34258309&postcount=13) and here [rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=34258309&postcount=16](http://rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=34258309&postcount=16) . Also i have commented to make sure the answer is found. [rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=45839239&postcount=4551](http://rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=45839239&postcount=4551) Thankyou for down-voting, because not everyone is perfect like you. –